# i want to find the factorial of a given number using recursive function in c.what's wrong with the following program?

Tags: c, function, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int i);
void main()
{
    int j;

    j=fact(4);

    printf("%d",j);
}

int fact(int i){
    int x=i;static int tot=1;

    if(x<1){
        tot=x*fact(x-1);
    }

    return tot;
}
```

Please help me with this code. What is wring in this code?

Comment: Homework?  Also, you need to fix the formatting.  You can put 4 spaces at the beginning of each code line as a start.

Comment: if(x<1)? are you sure about this..?

Comment: hahaha...not homework...have an exam on 9th...need to learn recursives..:)

Comment: "Recursion", not "recursives".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a base condition in the fact function.

You need to check:

```
 if(i == 1){
    return 1;
 }else{

   return i * fact(i - 1);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(x<1)
```

Are you sure you didn't mean `x > 1`?

Also, I would get rid of `static` in your declaration of `tot`.  This treats `tot` similarly to a global variable.  You don't need that. Since `tot` is always assigned before read it looks like it's not harmful here, but generally speaking it seems like a red flag.

Comment: `static` is wrong here because if the function is called more than once, it won't get reset to 1 for the start of the next recursive chain.

Comment: But it is called once here.  Hence I say it's not harmful for his example.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You misprinted in if statement, it should be

```
if(x > 1) {
   tot=x*fact(x-1);
}
```

EDIT: Also `tot` must be non-static.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the `static` in your `tot` declaration.